# Need help displaying values in a loop / array program C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, output

I'm trying to write a program to count and display the heights of students taller than 60 inches.  For example:  I need it to count and display the number of students taller than 60 inches and display their respective heights.  I am unsure of how to store the separate values and display their height.  I have gotten the program to count the number of students taller than 60 inches, but I need help displaying their specific height.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double count60 = 0.0;
    double height[10];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {
        height[x] = 0.0;
    }

    cout << "You are asked to enter heights of 10 students. "<< endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter height of a student: ";
        cin >> height[x];
    if (height[x] > 60)
    {
        count60 = count60 + 1;
    }       
    }

    cout << "The number of students taller than 60 inches: "<< count60 << endl;
    cout << "The heights of these students are: "

    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should consider writing increments as "++x", rather than "x = x + 1". It's better style. Also, count60 should be an int, not a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go... Not the best in terms of space utilization but avoids STL.

```
        #include <iostream>

        using namespace std;

        int main()
        {
            int count60 = 0;
            double height[10];
            double maxheight[10];
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
            {
                height[x] = 0.0;
            }

            cout << "You are asked to enter heights of 10 students. "<< endl;
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
            {
                cout << "Enter height of a student: ";
                cin >> height[x];
            if (height[x] > 60)
            {
                maxheight[count60] = height[x];
                count60 = count60 + 1;
            }       
            }

            cout << "The number of students taller than 60 inches: "<< count60 << endl;

            for (int i = 0; i < count60; i = i + 1)
            {
               cout<<"The heights of these students are: "<< maxheight[i] << endl;
            }

            system("pause"); 
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I totally understand where your problem lies.

It's clear from the code you've given you know how to:

- iterate through an array (your `for` statement for input);
- decide if something is greater than 60 (your `if` statement for updating count); and
- output a variable (your penultimate `cout <<` statement.

Hence it should be a simple matter to combine those with something like:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1) {
    if (height[x] > 60) {
        cout << height << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add, using '\n' instead of endl will mean that the buffer is not flushed after each call.

Comment: Yes, and I suspect, like C, if it's going to a terminal (if it can be "determined to refer to an interactive device"), it will get flushed per line. If it's not, it doesn't need to be line-flushed. In any case it's irrelevant here since flushing is not needed (and endl is inefficient in that case).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double count60 = 0.0;
double height[10];
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
{
    height[x] = 0.0;
}

cout << "You are asked to enter heights of 10 students. "<< endl;
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
{
    cout << "Enter height of a student: ";
    cin >> height[x];
if (height[x] > 60)
{
    count60 = count60 + 1;
}       
}

cout << "The number of students taller than 60 inches: "<< count60 << endl;
cout << "The heights of these students are: ";
for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
    if(height[i]>60)
        cout<<' '<<height[i];
cout<<endl;

return 0;
```

}

By the way, I think count60 should better be an unsigned int.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `std::vector`. They are basically a wrapper around an array and allow you to add values dynamically. In this case you would add the code:

```
#include <vector> // obviously with the rest of the includes.

std::vector<int> tallPeople;
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
{
    if (height[x] > 60)
    {
        count60 = count60 + 1;
        tallPeople.push_back(height[x]);
    }   
}

//...

for (int num = 0; num < tallPeople.size(); num++)
{
    cout << tallPeople[num] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove duplicates then do this

```
//bubble sort
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<10;j++)
    {
        if(height[i]>height[j])
        {
            double temp = height[i];
            height[i] = height[j];
            height[j] = temp;
        }       
    }
}   
//print
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(height[i]>60 && (i==0 || height[i]!= height[i-1]))   
    {
        cout << ' ' << height[i];
    }   
}
```